# Mutually Exclusive Queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

### Question

How would you role an IF...ELSE that produces mutually exclusive results into a query that produces the same results?

### Use Case

As the principal (currently logged in user) I can get a list of users in my organization. If I'm assigned to any departments then the list of users is a smaller set that are assigned to the same departments.

### Example

```
DECLARE @organizationId int = 421;
DECLARE @userId int = 1138;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers WHERE organizationId = @organizationId AND userId = @userId)
  -- Get user IDs in the same department(s) as the principal.
  SELECT du.userId
  FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers AS du
  JOIN (
        -- Get department IDs assigned to the principal.
        SELECT departmentId
        FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers
        WHERE organizationId = @organizationId
          AND userId = @userId) AS j
    ON du.departmentId = j.departmentId
  WHERE du.organizationId = @organizationId
ELSE
  -- Get all user IDs in the organization.
  SELECT userId
  FROM dbo.OrganizationsUsers
  WHERE organizationId = @organizationId
```

Comment: It seems like the solution would be some kind of LEFT JOIN that is conditionally forced to an INNER JOIN if the principal is assigned to any departments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a union with the "if" condition added to each where clause:

```
SELECT du.userId
FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers AS du
JOIN (  SELECT departmentId
        FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers
        WHERE organizationId = @organizationId
          AND userId = @userId) AS j
    ON du.departmentId = j.departmentId
WHERE du.organizationId = @organizationId
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers WHERE organizationId = @organizationId AND userId = @userId)
UNION
SELECT userId
FROM dbo.OrganizationsUsers
WHERE organizationId = @organizationId
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers WHERE organizationId = @organizationId AND userId = @userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT du.userId as UserId,
            'Department' as UserType // remove this line unnecessary
      FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers AS du
      JOIN (
            -- Get department IDs assigned to the principal.
            SELECT departmentId
            FROM dbo.DepartmentsUsers
            WHERE organizationId = @organizationId
              AND userId = @userId) AS j
        ON du.departmentId = j.departmentId
      WHERE du.organizationId = @organizationId

      UNION ALL

      -- Get all user IDs in the organization.
      SELECT userId as UserId,
             'Organization' as UserType // remove this line unnecessary
      FROM dbo.OrganizationsUsers
      WHERE organizationId = @organizationId
```

Comment: Need just one of the result sets. Not both combined. The business case is mutually exclusive.