# Optionally Force LEFT to INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

### Question

My question evolved from my last ([Mutually Exclusive Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248213/mutually-exclusive-queries)). My query has evolved. I need to get all the users in the organization. Optionally I need to filter that list down do just users in my department if I'm assigned to a department. Can you help?

### Approach

I'm trying to force a `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` with `EXISTS` in my `WHERE` clause. What do you think?

### Example

```
CREATE TABLE #OrganizationsUsers (
  OrganizationId int,
  UserId int,
  PRIMARY KEY (OrganizationId, UserId)
);
CREATE TABLE #DepartmentsUsers (
  DepartmentId int,
  UserId int,
  PRIMARY KEY (DepartmentId, UserId)
);

INSERT #OrganizationsUsers VALUES
(1, 33),
(1138, 421),
(1138, 1),
(1138, 2),
(1138, 3),
(1138, 4),
(1138, 5);

INSERT #DepartmentsUsers VALUES
(11, 421),
(11, 1),
(11, 2),
(12, 3),
(12, 4);

DECLARE @OrganizationId int = 1138;
DECLARE @PrincipalUserId int = 421;

SELECT ou.UserId
FROM #OrganizationsUsers AS ou
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT du.UserId
  FROM #DepartmentsUsers AS du
  JOIN #DepartmentsUsers AS du2 ON du.DepartmentId = du2.DepartmentId
  WHERE du2.UserId = @PrincipalUserId
) AS lj ON ou.UserId = lj.UserId
WHERE ou.OrganizationId = @OrganizationId
  AND ((EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #DepartmentsUsers WHERE UserId = @PrincipalUserId AND OrganizationId = @OrganizationId) AND lj.UserId IS NOT NULL)
    OR lj.UserId IS NULL);

DROP TABLE #OrganizationsUsers;
DROP TABLE #DepartmentsUsers;
```

### Expected Output

When the principal is not in the DeparmentsUsers table:
**UserId**
1
2
3
4
5
421

When the principal is assigned to department 11:
**UserId**
1
2
421

When the principal is assigned to department 12:
**UserId**
3
4
421

Comment: If you actually want help, we need data to test with... Check out this link to see how to properly ask a sql coding question... https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I've updated the question to add the essence of your request with the potential that you might be able to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was having a complete `WHERE` clause that toggles between the user being assigned to a department or not. I needed `EXISTS ()` or `NOT EXISTS()` with the `LEFT JOIN` column being `NULL` or `NOT NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE #OrganizationsUsers (
  OrganizationId int,
  UserId int,
  PRIMARY KEY (OrganizationId, UserId)
);

CREATE TABLE #DepartmentsUsers (
  DepartmentId int,
  UserId int,
  PRIMARY KEY (DepartmentId, UserId)
);

INSERT #OrganizationsUsers VALUES
(1, 33),
(1138, 421),
(1138, 1),
(1138, 2),
(1138, 3),
(1138, 4),
(1138, 5);

INSERT #DepartmentsUsers VALUES
--(12, 421),
(11, 1),
(11, 2),
(12, 3),
(12, 4);

DECLARE @OrganizationId int = 1138;
DECLARE @PrincipalUserId int = 421;

SELECT ou.UserId
FROM #OrganizationsUsers AS ou
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT du.UserId
  FROM #DepartmentsUsers AS du
  JOIN #DepartmentsUsers AS du2 ON du.DepartmentId = du2.DepartmentId
  WHERE du2.UserId = @PrincipalUserId
) AS lj ON ou.UserId = lj.UserId
WHERE ou.OrganizationId = @OrganizationId
  AND ((EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #DepartmentsUsers WHERE UserId = @PrincipalUserId AND OrganizationId = @OrganizationId) AND lj.UserId IS NOT NULL)
    OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #DepartmentsUsers WHERE UserId = @PrincipalUserId AND OrganizationId = @OrganizationId) AND lj.UserId IS NULL));

DROP TABLE #OrganizationsUsers;
DROP TABLE #DepartmentsUsers;
```